# dismissViewControllerAnimated causing the same view controller to load again

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios7

My scenario is the following:

1. When the application load, the first controller is A
2. The first time the application starts, it loads controller B which shows a video. A loads B using `performSegueWithIdentifier` in its `viewDidAppear` method. B
3. B shows the video using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. B recognizes that the video is finished using `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` and than performs:
   `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

The dismiss call causing B to reload (the movies plays again) and the following error appears in the console:

> : CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your logic to present ViewController B in the `viewDidAppear:` method of ViewController A.

When B is done and dismisses, the `viewDidAppear:` of A will be called (again) which in turn will present B again and the cycle will continue till something rots.

### Basically:

1. `viewDidLoad` of A
2. `viewDidAppear:` of A
3. B presents
4. B dismisses
5. `viewDidAppear:` of A
6. B presents
   ...

You should re-think your logic because at this point, there are many ways to go about this.

Or... if this movie must play only once then you can present B in the `viewDidLoad` of A.

Comment: There is no problem with the logic - A calls B in viewDidAppear only once. viewDidAppear of A is not called at all after the dismiss call

Comment: @ErikSapir : ok. then... kindly add the relevant code in your question

Comment: ViewDidAppear of A SHOULD be being called after B dismisses (Step 5 above).  If not, something is very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a property like didMoviePlay and check that in `viewDidAppear:` to decide whether the movie played or not. That way if there's an error with movie playback you can decide how to proceed from there.

Comment: This is what i am doing - viewDiDAppear of A is called only once. After trying to dismiss B, viewDidAppear not even called

Answer (score 0):

The call to `dismissViewControllerAnimated` will cause `viewDidAppear` to be invoked again on the first view controller A.

But you can distinguish between the first time the this view controller is begin presented using the method `- (BOOL)[UIViewController isBeingPresented]`.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  if ([self isBeingPresented]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
  }
}
```